# Error java.net.SocketTimeoutException en Android con API REST

Tags: android, android-studio, json, api

Tengo un aplicacion que envia JSON's a un controlador para alli manejarlos y guardarlos a la Base de Datos, he probado y ya los guarda correctamente, el problema que tengo es que no obtengo la resuesta de exito del servidor sino que tengo un mensaje el Log

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
```

Me pregunto si se debe al tiempo que dura la operacion sera mucho o si la conexion se pierde, para hacer la peticion uso `Okhhtps`:
Este es el metodo que uso para enviar el `JSON`

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
public static final MediaType JSON
        = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

private void send(String tkn) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray json = getInsertCapturas();

    String url = "http://100.167.100.80/proyecto_sinave_jwt/web/app_dev.php/api/entomologicas";
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json.toString());
    final okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + tkn)
            .build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Log.i("***okhttp**", String.valueOf(e));
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                final String res = response.body().string();
                SubirDatos.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.i("***okhttp**", res);
                        tvja.setText(res);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Como les menciono lleva el `JSON` y lo guarda en la base pero metodo `onFAilure` obtiene el error

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Comment: El problema no es el código es la url, cuales son las propiedades adecuadas para que funcione,por ejemplo que body necesita ?. verifica que funcione correctamente con su administrador. Esto es **Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir**

Comment: lo  he resuelto el problema era del servidor que retornaba un error por la configuracion quye tenia al correr un scrip php